# How do I write a script to test carousel arrows part of a image gallery

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[Image Gallery Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGki5.jpg)

I have this element on which I am writing a script to click on the arrows until it is greyed out.

The total number of images on each image gallery vary and are dynamic in nature so that total number of images is always unknown.

How can we write a script in Selenium Webdriver to identify these dynamic number of images and click on the arrow until it is greyed out.

Thanks.
Ps: New to Selenium. Trying to learn.

Comment: Please before asking how to do something, try to show some tries you've done or some efforts you've made to understand. And possibly carefully read [best practices to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: provide any HTML or code.

Comment: This is my code I put together